# No tag library could be found with this URI using ESAPI

Tags: jsp, esapi

I've just added this tag to the JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="esapi"   uri="http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API"%>
```

But I got this error when compiling

```
  [java] No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
     [java] <%@ taglib prefix="esapi"   uri="http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API"%>
```

Comment: Indeed was it was the web.xml file  avgvstvs

Comment: Feel free to post your solution, other people might have the same problem in the future!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/esapi.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
```